# Swift - Strange method signature syntax

Tags: swift

I am unable to understand the following method signature I went through lastly while working on an open source framework:

```
public func myFunc<A: TypeOfA, B: TypeOfB, C: TypeOfC>
    (someA: A)
    -> (someB: B)
    -> ReturnedType  {

// BODY OF THE FUNC

}
```

Why is there 2 return arrows '->'? Does anyone know where I could get more info about this syntax? Did find anything in the Apple Swift doc.

I am NOT talking about the generics but about the way the parameters are declared.

And yes this compiles fine with xcode 7.3

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function takes one argument, `someA: A`, and **returns another function**.

The function it returns takes `someB: B` and returns `ReturnedType`.

This is equivalent to:

```
public func myFunc<...>(someA: A) -> ((someB: B) -> ReturnedType) {
    ...
}
```

or

```
typealias SecondFunction = (someB: B) -> ReturnedType
public func myFunc<...>(someA: A) -> SecondFunction {
    ...
}
```